# Do Android phones always have status bars and iPhones always NOT have status bars?

Tags: android, ios, statusbar

The Androids I've seen all have status bars, so any app running will be rendered underneath it. The iPhones I've seen all do NOT have status bars, so the content of any app running is rendered behind the time, battery life, etc.

Is this the case for all Androids and iPhones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android apps have an app bar at the top, whose visibility can be controlled through the parent theme that is applied to the application to be either `VISIBLE` or `GONE`. You can control its visibility on each layout, based on your needs.

Similar concept is present in iOS, where we have a `safeArea`, where a `View` can inflate without worrying about what content will go in the upper left and right nodges.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I'm wondering though is do all Android phones have the visibility set to `VISIBLE`, and do all iPhones have the `safeArea` turned off? In other words, is there a status bar by default on all Androids, and no status bar by default on all iPhones?

Comment: It depends on your base theme, by default the Android studio new project setups the new app with an app bar, but that can be disabled. So does the iOS as well.

Comment: Re "So does iOS as well": I understand then what Android does by default, but what is it that iOS does by default? A default React Native app that I make doesn't seem to have a `safeArea`, ie. content is rendered behind the time etc.

Comment: Not sure with hybrid apps, but in iOS, a default view will have SafeArea as its children by default. Maybe that is something the IDE does or could be the sdk. You are still allowed to work in the view, but because of the nodge since iPhone 10, they introduced SafeArea which exclude the node cases.